# Oracle throwing "Inconsistent datatype" error (ORA-00932) when trying to insert my DataFrame using to_sql()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have a pandas dataframe which I want to insert into my oracle table.

First, I created a sql aclehmey engine using the create_engine() function. This engine was used in the Dataframe.to_sql function

Next, I tried inserting my pandas dataframe into the oracle table using

```py
df.to_sql(oracle_table_name,engine,schema=oracle_database_name)
```

Now, I am getting this error:

> Inconsistent datatype. Expected clob got dates .

However, my oracle table HAS NO CLOB COLUMNS. Why is this error being thrown then?

Comment: Before writing the dataframe to oracle table cross check and cast the columns.

Comment: You think you have no CLOB columns. Does Oracle feel the same way?

Comment: On Stack Overflow it's best to include the code you tried.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output from `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<your table name>'`